# How can I insert only if a column changed since last entry?

Tags: mysql, sql

#### Problem description

`RDMS : 10.1.23-MariaDB`

```
create table product_log
(
    id int auto_increment,
    id_product mediumint(6) unsigned not null,
    id_store int not null,
    quantity int default 0 not null,
    date_log date null,
    constraint product_log_pk
        primary key (id)
);

create table product_store
(
  id int auto_increment,
  id_product mediumint(6) unsigned not null,
  id_store int not null,
  quantity int default 0 not null,
  constraint product_store_pk
    primary key (id)
);

INSERT INTO product_store SET id_product = 1, id_store = 1, quantity = 6;
INSERT INTO product_log(
  SELECT NULL, ps.id_product, ps.id_store, ps.quantity, CURRENT_DATE() 
  FROM product_store ps WHERE ps.id_store = 1
);
INSERT INTO product_log(
  SELECT NULL, ps.id_product, ps.id_store, ps.quantity, CURRENT_DATE() 
  FROM product_store ps WHERE ps.id_store = 1
); -- I wish this does not add a line because quantity has not changed
UPDATE product_store SET quantity = 12 WHERE id_product = 1 AND id_store = 1;
INSERT INTO product_log(
  SELECT NULL, ps.id_product, ps.id_store, ps.quantity, CURRENT_DATE() 
  FROM product_store ps WHERE ps.id_store = 1
); -- I wish this does add a line because quantity has changed
INSERT INTO product_log(
  SELECT NULL, ps.id_product, ps.id_store, ps.quantity, CURRENT_DATE() 
  FROM product_store ps WHERE ps.id_store = 1
); -- I wish this does not add a line because quantity has not changed
```

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecc77c/1

---

I have a table `product_log` formed with the following fields :

```
id (int not null primary key auto increment)`
id_product (int not null foreign key)
id_store (int not null foreign key)
quantity(int unsigned not null)
date_log(date)
```

I have a query in a cron job that loops over my stores in PHP and executes this query for all my stores :

```
INSERT INTO product_log(
  SELECT NULL, ps.id_product, ps.id_store, ps.quantity, CURRENT_DATE() 
  FROM product_store ps WHERE ps.id_store = :store
)
```

`:store` being a wildcard (I use PHP's PDO to do the query)

My query currently work well, but **I would like to insert the row only if the quantity has changed since the last time it has been logged.**

#### Solutions tried

I tried using a unique contraint and a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause but **it will not work because I can not check if the duplicate quantity is the last log** (if quantity has gone 2 -> 1 -> 2, i want to log the entry because 2 <> 1, but the unique constraint will step in, and I don't want that.)

I think there might be some `SELF JOIN` shenanigans but I guess I'm not skilled enough to find it. If someone could provide a query that would solve my problem, it would be appreciated.

---

I also thought of this query :

```
    INSERT INTO product_log(
        SELECT NULL, ps.id_product, ps.id_store, ps.quantity, CURRENT_DATE() 
        FROM product_store ps
        WHERE ps.id_store = :store AND ps.quantity <> (
          SELECT IF(COUNT(pl.id) = 0, 0, pl.quantity
) FROM product_log pl 
          WHERE pl.id_store = :store AND pl.id_product = ps.id_product ORDER BY pl.date_log DESC, pl.id DESC LIMIT 1
        )
    );
```

This is quite close, but it does add an entry if I have already logged a quantity change, because

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(pl.id) = 0, 0, pl.quantity) FROM product_log pl 
      WHERE pl.id_store = :store AND pl.id_product = ps.id_product ORDER BY pl.date_log DESC, pl.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Will fetch the first quantity of the table, and not the last.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I provided a link to a SQL Fiddle. Thanks for pointing out. For the sake of the example, I dropped the FK's as they are not really the subject of my problem here.

Comment: I'd do this by keeping track of the prior `quantity`, and then adding a condition `WHERE ... ps.quantity <> :quantity` to the SELECT. That will result in inserting zero rows unless the quantity is different from the prior one.

Comment: You mean you would add some column `prior_quantity` to the table `product_log` ? I'm not sure I'm precisely getting what you mean.

Comment: You check `id_localisation` column in INSERT which is absent in DDL... you want to refer to *last time it has been logged* whereas in sample data you have 3 duplicates by `date_log` column... there are more problems. Please put your question in order.

Comment: @Akina The question has been edited. Thanks for your remarks. Feel free to ask is something is still not clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a conditional check as follows.

Although i havent worked in Maria-db i am assuming windowing functions work over there

```
INSERT INTO product_log(
  SELECT NULL, ps.id_product, ps.id_store, ps.quantity, CURRENT_DATE() 
    FROM product_store ps     
   WHERE ps.id_localisation = :store
    AND NOT EXISTS (select *
                     from (SELECT t.*,row_number() over(partition by t.id_product
                                                                    ,t.id_store
                                                     order by date_log desc) as rnk
                             FROM product_log t
                           )x    
                      where x.rnk=1 /*gets you the latest entry in log*/
                        and x.id_product=ps.id_product /*same product*/
                        and x.id_store=ps.id_store /*same store*/
                        and x.quantity=ps.quantity /*and if its has same quantity*/
                      )
                  )
```

Comment: Window functions were first introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0.